# How send emails from shared email (or delegation email) with JakartaMail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails from shared email (or delegation email) with JakartaMail. I googled it, but found only how to read a shared mail box, not how to send emails from it.

```java
private Session getSession(Company company) {
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3");
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.start-tls-enable", true);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust",trust);
    
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
    return Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
        }
    });
```

This is my code to get the session to send emails with my email account, not shared ones. How can I fix it to send emails from shared emails?

Comment: What does “shared email” mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't send email "from a mailbox".  You send email with a `From:` address.

You can use any valid email address as the `From:` *provided* that the mail server that you are using to outbound the email permits it.

So what is permitted?

Well it depends on how your outbound email server is set up.

- Some may allow you to use any email address.  (Bad idea!)
- Some will allow you to use any local email address (for some definition of local).
- Some will only allow to use *your* authenticated email address as the `From:` address.

Ask the outbound mail server's administrators or check its documentation to find out what the rules / policy is.